# PayPal JS SDK server integration - including additional parameters

Tags: javascript, paypal

I wanted to integrate the new JS button. I'm on [this page](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) trying to figure out how to do this. I understand how it's supposed to work, but I don't get how to call a server script to handle the database updates.

It seems this line:

```
return fetch('/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/' + data.orderID + '/capture/', {method: 'post'}
```

is calling a script, but how can I include arguments?

Answer (score 0):

In the line  you quote, the content of `data.orderID` becomes a path (URL) argument, and that URL is fetched. This URL needs to be a route on your server.

If you want to pass additional arguments, or put the order ID in the body of the request instead of the URL, you can do so. Use `body` in the options to `fetch`, and give it a JSON object/string. Something like:

```js
return fetch('/path/on/your/server/to/capture/order', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: {
    id: data.orderID,
    your_argument_name: 'some data';
  }
});
```

On the server end handling the route, you'll need to deserialize that JSON object. Plenty of guides out there on how to read JSON input for whatever backend environment you're using (notably you do *not* use PHP's $_POST as that is for form encoded data only)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the database updates are happening in the '/path/on/your/server/to/capture/order' url ? For what I saw on fetch, it calls a file, then pass the results of this file to the next function in variable orderData ? The file was created using createOrder function I guess. But fetch seems to only "fetch" files, I cannot use it to update a sql database. Do I have to use ajax after I received the orderData variable ? Thank you again

Comment: fetch is an ajax call to your server. Do what you need to do on your server, including capturing the payment via API, and return the result (propagating any errors)

Comment: the createOrder function has the initial fetch to call your server to have it create the order (for the correct amount), via the v2/checkout/orders API

Comment: Ok thanks you. The only thing that remains mysterious to me is the tranfert of data between the JavaScript call and the backend file. It seems that data is being transfered using post, but if i use this data in the backend, isn't there a risk of data tampering ?

Comment: Your server should verify the data is sane before using it for anything. That's the point.